# How to store search result by using session?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to store search result from users and display the result again when they do postback.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @JohnConde that's no longer an official close reason; We now call these questions "unclear"

Comment: @JanDvorak: if they don't want that reason given, then they should also remove the very option that lets us set arbitrary close votes. imho, the removal of the minimal understanding option is a BAD decision. At most the actual text should've been modified into a more polite version of "don't get us to do your job for you". But that's a discussion for meta... not here.

Comment: @MarcB I agree with that sentiment; however, the official stance seems to be "if the question is clear and reasonably scoped (3 lines, not 300), then it shouldn't be closed, merely downvoted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     <?php session_start();  //to start session

      $_SESSION['search_result'] = $_REQUEST['search_result'];

     //$_REQUEST['search_result'] is the data you get from GET Mehthod or POST Method of variable search_result


     ?>



      To acess it on other page

      <?php

      session_start();
      $search_result = $_SESSION['search_result'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can:

```
//page 1
session_start();
$_SESSION['postback'] = serialize($msg);
//page 2
session_start();
$msg = isset($_SESSION['postback'])?unserialize($_SESSION['postback']):'';
```

but,do not use session like this.